# How to start two Django applications at the same server?

Tags: python, django, wagtail, saleor

I am going to use both Saleor and Wagtail in the same project.
Saleor will take care of all shop related functionalities and Wagtail will be the CMS for everything else (it is a lot of content).

What I need as advice is to how can I run both applications from the same server?

E.g. wagtail will serve urls like www.example.com/about-us etc. and Saleor will serve www.example.com/shop

I understand that this will happen in urls.py but, what confuses me is when I run ./manage.py runserver at the Saleor end how is this going to start the wagtail server.

So basically how can I start both apps with one single management command and share the resource? (it is still a localhost project)

I will be thankful if somebody can show me some web resources about the topic if my approach is correct or can point in a better direction.

Comment: Given what I know of waigtail and what I've just seen of saleor, cobbling both together in a single Django project might not be that easy. You might have more success keeping them as distinct projects (eventually sharing the database), and use your front server to serve one as the main domain and the other as a subdomain.

Comment: If you have a single project whose INSTALLED_APPS contains everything you need from both Wagtail and Saleor, then ./manage.py runserver will Just Work - there's a single server that directs requests to either Wagtail or Saleor as appropriate, not a "Wagtail server" and "Saleor server". Perhaps you can elaborate on what's confusing you?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers wouldn't that be a performance issue? Loading the shop when going to the subdomain?

Comment: @gasman you answered my question about having all dependencies in INSTALLED_APPS. However, which admin panel will serve both applications?

Comment: @HenryLynx if you have both wagtail and saleor in the same project, you only have one single django instance, so it's actually one single "application".  And no, having two distinct django instances instead (one for saleor and one for wagtail) is not going to degrade performances, why should it ?

Comment: Oh and yes: Wagtail doc has a chapter about integrating wagtail into an existing django project, so since saleor is already bundled as a full project, if you want to try and run both in the same project, it looks like your best bet is to first fork saleor, install it as your project, then follow wagtail's instructions to add it to the project.

Comment: I did integrate Wagtail into Saleor as advised from you @brunodesthuilliers. Thank you!